# Apache Tika get allowable mime typs for extension

Tags: playframework, content-type, apache-tika

I am using [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to help support validation of user uploaded files. I am able to extract the MIME type of the upload using Tika:

```
MetaData metaData = new MetaData();
metaData.set(TikaMetaDataKeys.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
String mime = new TikaConfig().getDetector.detect(fileInputStream, metaData);
```

Now that I have the correct MIME for the upload, I want to approve the upload *only* if the Tika extracted MIME is valid for the extension of the uploaded file.

For instance, say I allow only PDF uploads, I'd like the following sequence:

1. Make sure the extension is `.pdf`, if not then refuse upload
2. Make sure the MIME type of the file is valid for the allowable extension, if not then refuse upload

It is step 2 that I am trying to figure out. Tika has a way to get the preferred extensions given the MIME (see [getExtension](https://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/mime/MimeType.html#getExtension())), but I want to go the other way around: given the extension, check that the MIME is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to actually run detection a second time, supplying on the file name and/or file extension, and see what mimetype Tika reports that extension as belonging to

Your code would then be something like:

```
TikaConfig tika = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();

MetaData metaData = new MetaData();
metaData.set(TikaMetaDataKeys.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
String bodyMime = tika.getDetector.detect(fileInputStream, metaData);

metaData = new MetaData();
metaData.set(TikaMetaDataKeys.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
String nameMime = tika.getDetector.detect(null, metaData);
```

Depending on your requirements, you might then want to see if the two mime types are the same, or if they're related. You can use the [MediaTypeRegistry](http://tika.apache.org/1.7/api/org/apache/tika/mime/MediaTypeRegistry.html) to check if a give mime type is a child of another one or not.